# From array of objects want to get date range wise data using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

From array of objects want to get date range wise data using mongoose.

This is my code:

```js
sessionSlot.aggregate([
        {
          "$match": {
            'userID': loginUser._id,
            'sessions':  { "date": { "$gte": req.body.from, "$lt": req.body.to } } 
          },
        },
        {$unwind: "$sessions" },
        {
          "$project": {
            "sessions": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": "$sessions",
                "as": "s1",
                "cond": {
                  "$and": [
                    { "$gte": [ "$$s1.date", new Date(req.body.from) ]},
                    { "$lt": [ "$$s1.date", new Date(req.body.to) ]}
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ], (err, result) => {
        console.log('..........', result);
      })
```

This is my schema:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

var sessionSlotSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    userID      : { type: String },
    mail        : { type: String },
    slotFlag    : { type: Boolean },
    slotID      : { type: String },
    slotType    : { type: String },
    sessions    : [{
                    date         : { type: String, default:null },
                    userID       : { type: String, default:null },
                    therapyType  : { type: String, default:null },
                    price        : { type: String, default:null },
                    startDate    : { type: String, default:null },
                    totalSession : { type: String, default:null },
                    status       : { type: String, default:'empty' },
                    profilepic   : { type: String, default:null },
                    fullname     : { type: String },
                    autoBook     : { type: Boolean, default:false },
                    time         : { type: String, default:null },
                    duration     : { type: String, default:null },
                    reminders    : { type: String, default:null }
    }]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('sessionSlot', sessionSlotSchema, 'sessionSlot');
```

I am getting error like MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$filter'.
So where I am mistaken?

I am passing two dates in request body in Date format. 
req.body.from and req.body.to are two fields from which I want the data.

Comment: `$filter` was introduce in v3.2 - which version are you on?

Comment: I am using mongoose version 4.5

Comment: Lovely. Which version of MongoDB, though? ;)

Comment: MongoDB version is 2.1

Comment: That is really old... Would you be able to update?

Comment: update to which version?

Comment: As high as you can possibly go. I would recommend v3.6.5. Mind you, you might want (not necessarily required) to upgrade Mongoose to the latest version, too.